# Cannot create Ado.net entity data model in visual studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

I cannot create an Ado.net entity data model in my mvc .netcore application in visual studio community 2019

I have the tools installed in the installer and also EntityFramework as a package

[This is how it looks for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecVjn.png)

[This is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqKot.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET core essentially took away the GUI method of generating an entity data model.   You need to leverage the powershell commands for EFCore.  For instance,  if you have a database already in place you’ll want to look at the Scaffold options to generator your model.